# Specify an HTML table's <tbody> element as a region in Marionette for Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

**Problem**

Using a [Backbone.Marrionette.Layout](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md) to present some tabular data. The `<tbody>` portion of the table is a [Backbone.Marionette.Region](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md) that is meant to display a [Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md).

I can not figure out how to do this using Marionette's "Regions" without messing up the table display by inserting an extra HTML element inside the `<tbody>` element.

**Example Code**

The `Layout` looks like this:

```
Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template:...
    regions:{
        list_region: '#list-region'
    }
    onRender:function(){
        var collection = new TheCollection()
        var collectionView = new TheCollectionView({
            collection: collection
        })
        // PROBLEM: The region seems to needs its own HTML element,
        //   and the CollectionView also seems to need its on HTML
        //   element, but as far as I can see, there is only room 
        //    for one element: <tbody>?
        this.list_region.show(collectionView);
});
```

The template for the Layout comprises the entire table:

```
<table>

    <tbody id='list-region'>

    </tbody>

    <tfoot id='footer-region'>
        Some other stuff goes here that is not a collection, so I was able 
        to make the View's 'tagName' property 'tr', which worked fine.
    </tfoot>

</table>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is the intent of this layout solely to facilitate a table? If so, you should look at using a CompositeView instead.

```
RowView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: "tr",
  template: ...
});

TableView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  template: ...,

  childView: RowView,

  childViewContainer: "#list-region"
});
```

That's pretty much it. This will render all of your itemViews in to the tbody.

Comment: Just wanted to write a quick thank-you. I've already a referred back to this a few times.

Comment: In this case, what if you wanted to use an `ItemView` for aggregate data in a `tfoot`, would you just manually handle that as a child view since you cannot use the region model for that? Is that a use case for  [Backbone.Babysitter](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter) with the `CompositeView`?

Comment: @PaulTyng - I have that exact same issue. The tfoot is itself a region. I'm going to have to rethink my layouts and views.

Comment: CompositeView is deprecated and will be removed. In addition, if you need an empty view that does not include headers or footers, if one does not use collection view one must resort to hackery to remove the extra material. https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/828#issuecomment-178823618

Answer (score 2):

Marionette 3 deprecated the `CompositeView` class. Instead, a region can now overwrite its `el` with the rendered contents of the
inner View with the [new `replaceElement` option](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.0.0-pre.4/marionette.region.html#additional-options).

See [this example](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.0.0-pre.4/marionette.collectionview.html#tables-using-marionette-3) to render a table:

```
var RowView = Marionette.View.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',
  template: '#row-template'
});

var TableBody = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: 'tbody',
  childView: RowView
});

var TableView = Marionette.View.extend({
  tagName: 'table',
  className: 'table table-hover',
  template: '#table',

  regions: {
    body: {
      el: 'tbody',
      replaceElement: true
    }
  },

  onRender: function() {
    this.showChildView('body', new TableBody({
      collection: this.collection
    }));
  }
});

var list = new Backbone.Collection([
  {id: 1, text: 'My text'},
  {id: 2, text: 'Another Item'}
]);

var myTable = new TableView({
  collection: list
});

myTable.render();
```