# CompositeView and/or CollectionView won't render table headers

Tags: backbone.js, view, marionette

I'm having some problems rendering headers in a composite or collection view. I tried both, but this simply won't render.

Let me show you a little bit of my code:

```
// composite view
define(function(require) {

    var BusinessTableTemplate = require("text!templates/BusinessTableTemplate.html");
    var BusinessRowView = require("views/BusinessRowView");
    var Marionette = require("marionette");

    return BusinessTableView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

        tagName: "table",
        className: "table table-hover",
        template: BusinessTableTemplate,
        itemView: BusinessRowView,
        appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView){
            collectionView.$("tbody").append(itemView.el);
        }

    });

});

// BusinessTableTemplate
<script type="text/template">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Building</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Website</th>
            <th>Categories</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>

</script>

// itemview
define(function(require) {

    var BusinessRowTemplate = require("text!templates/BusinessRowTemplate.html");
    var Marionette = require("marionette");

    return BusinessRowView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        template: BusinessRowTemplate,
        tagName: "tr"

    });

});

// BusinessRowTemplate
<script type="text/template">

    <td>
        <%= name %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <% if (address) { %>
            <%= address %>
        <% } else { %>
            NA
        <% } %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <% if (building) { %>
            <%= building %>
        <% } else { %>
            NA
        <% } %>
    </td>
    <td>
    <td>
        <% _.each(phones, function(phone) { %>
            <span class="label label-default label-info"><%= phone %></span>
        <% }); %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <% if (website) { %>
            <%= website %>
        <% } else { %>
            NA
        <% } %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <% _.each(tags, function(category) { %>
            <span class="label label-default label-info"><%= category %></span>
        <% }); %>
    </td>
    <td>
        Ações
    </td>
</script>


// signal or event where I render the view
vent.on("search:seeAll", function(){
  if (self.results) {
    var businessDirectoryView = new BusinessDirectoryView();
    self.layout.modals.show(businessDirectoryView);
    var resultCollection = new Businesses(self.results, {renderInMap: false});
    var businessTableView = new BusinessTableView({
      collection: resultCollection
    });
    $("#businesses-container").html(businessTableView.render().$el);
  }
});
```

I followed a tutorial somewhere, but they did not specified headers for the table.

A little help here to render this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the Marionette JS version you are using?

Here is a fiddle using the version 2.4.1 (latest available) and it is working:

https://jsfiddle.net/aokrhw1w/2/

There are some changes in the composite view with previous versions, the 'itemView' was changed to 'childView'.

```
var BusinessTableView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
   tagName: "table",
   className: "table table-hover",
   template: '#BusinessTableTpl',
   childView: BusinessRowView,
   childViewContainer: "tbody",
   appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
                console.log('append');
                 this.$("tbody").append(itemView.el);
   }
});
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`CollectionView` renders one child view per model in a collection. It doesn't give you any way to add extra HTML like a header.

`CompositeView` renders collection items too, but you can also add extra HTML. Your example uses `CompositeView`, so you have made the right choice.

Because you can have custom HTML around the rendered collection, you need to tell Marionette where to render the collection item views. The `childViewContainer` property does that:

```
Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    tagName: "table",
    className: "table table-hover",
    template: BusinessTableTemplate,
    itemView: BusinessRowView,
    childViewContainer: 'tbody'
});
```

You don't need to use `attachHtml` for simple cases like this - it's for edge cases where you need to change Marionette's default behaviour.

See the [CompositeView docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.compositeview.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Marionette 3 deprecated the `CompositeView` class. Instead, a region can now overwrite its `el` with the rendered contents of the
inner View with the [new `replaceElement` option](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.0.0-pre.4/marionette.region.html#additional-options).

See [this example](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.0.0-pre.4/marionette.collectionview.html#tables-using-marionette-3) to render a table:

```
var RowView = Marionette.View.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',
  template: '#row-template'
});

var TableBody = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: 'tbody',
  childView: RowView
});

var TableView = Marionette.View.extend({
  tagName: 'table',
  className: 'table table-hover',
  template: '#table',

  regions: {
    body: {
      el: 'tbody',
      replaceElement: true
    }
  },

  onRender: function() {
    this.showChildView('body', new TableBody({
      collection: this.collection
    }));
  }
});

var list = new Backbone.Collection([
  {id: 1, text: 'My text'},
  {id: 2, text: 'Another Item'}
]);

var myTable = new TableView({
  collection: list
});

myTable.render();
```

Note to overzealous moderators: I gave the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38293619/1030527). Both questions are **not** duplicates but **do** refer to the same deprecated class. It makes no sense to spend time to "[tailor the answer to both questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104231)"; it's just a waste of time since the only important part is: "This class is deprecated, use that one instead. Here's an example and link to the doc".